# NMaximize vs. Maximize giving conflicting answers

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, taylor-series

I'm trying to find a relative error estimate of Sin[x]/x-1 using terms of the Taylor polynomial - however, I've run into some issues. If you plot the derivatives of the function, to get a feel for a maximum so Taylor's Inequality could be used, it looks like you get near infinity at 0. However, a few odd things happen.

If I use

```
Maximize[{D[Sin[x]/x-1,{x,15}],0<=x<=1},{x}] = {1100370038249 Cos[1] - 706539476355 Sin[1], {x -> 1}} = 0.050293
NMaximize[{D[Sin[x]/x-1,{x,15}],0<=x<=1},{x}] = {4.41964*10^105, {x -> 5.30083*10^-8}} and the message 'NMaximize::cvdiv: Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded.
Limit[D[Sin[x]/x-1,{x,15}], x -> 5.30083*10^-8 ] = 0.
```

Anyone know what's happening? I assume there's an odd rounding consequence, but I'd appreciate a complete explanation.

Comment: Try adding the option WorkingPrecision->64 to your NMaximize. Additional precision looks like it keeps it from being confused.

Comment: Yes, it's from roundoff error at machine precision.